# can't get file property using Multer

Tags: javascript, express, multer

I'm trying to upload an image from my form using **Multer**, when I insert the image everything works fine But when there is no image chosen I got an error.

- Here is multer config all uploaded images are stored in public/images/uploads:

> ```
> //handle file upload
>
> var storage = multer.diskStorage({
>   destination: function (req, file, cb) {
>     cb(null, 'public/images/uploads/')
>   },
>   filename: function (req, file, cb) {
>     cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now()+ '.jpg')
>   }
> });
> var upload = multer({ storage: storage })
> ```

Now I want to get back the value of **mainImageName** but when I don't insert any image an error occurs `cannot get property filename of undefined.`

- Here is the rest :

  ```
  //Submit new post
  router.post('/add', upload.single('mainimage'), function(req, res, next) {
  var title = req.body.title;
  var category = req.body.category;
  var body = req.body.body;
  var author = req.body.author;
  var date = new Date();

  if(req.file && req.file.mainimage){

      var mainImageName = req.file.filename;
      var mainImageMime = req.file.mainimage.mimetype;
      var mainImagePath = req.file.mainimage.path;
      var mainImageSize = req.file.mainimage.size;

  }else{

      //if there was no image uploaded!!
      //noimage.png should be placed in public/images/uploads
      mainImageName = 'noimage.png';
  }

  console.log(mainImageName); //always returns noimage.png !!

  //form validation
  req.checkBody('title', 'You forgot the title').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('body', 'Please fill in the body').notEmpty();

  //check errors
  var errors = req.validationErrors();

  if(errors){
  ```

  var mycategories = [];
    var categories = db.get('categories');
    categories.find({}, {}, function(err, categories) {

  ```
      for (i=0; i<categories.length; i++) {
            mycategories[i] = categories[i];
          }
   });
  res.render('addpost', {
          'pageTitle': 'Add Post',
          'errors': errors,
          'title': title,
          'body': body,
          'categories': mycategories

      });

  } else{
          var posts = db.get('posts');
          //submit Post
          posts.insert({   "title": title, 
                           "body": body,
                           "category": category,
                           "date": date,
                           "author": author,
                           "mainimage": mainImageName 

                   }, function(err, post) {
              if (err){
          res.send('There was an issue submitting the post.')
           } else {
              req.flash('success_msg', 'Post Submitted');
              res.location('/');
              res.redirect('/');
           }
           });
  }
  ```

  });

Comment: That's... right. If you do not pass a file, then `req.files` would be empty hence `req.files[0]` would be `undefined` hence `req.files[0].filename` would cause an error (since you are trying to get the property of an `undefined` object). Move the offending `console.log()` in the first IF statement and that should prevent the error from happening.

Comment: Thanks [Mikey](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1022914/mikey) but what I don't understand is whether  I pass a file or not **mainImageName** always returns noimage.png.

Comment: Edit your question with your route definition e.g. `app.post('whatever', upload...`

Comment: That's because you set it to "noimage.png" in your code: `var mainImageName = 'noimage.png'`

Comment: @fredrover I think he's trying to say it never enters the IF block when he does have an image.

Comment: [Mikey](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1022914/mikey) Yes it never hits the IF block even if an image is passed.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, the condition `if(req.file && req.file.mainimage)` was never met because `req.file.mainimage` is always undefined so I simply changed it to `if(req.file)` and it worked fine .

This is how it should look like:

```
if(req.file){

    var mainImageName = req.file.filename;
    var mainImageMime = req.file.mimetype;
    var mainImagePath = req.file.path;
    var mainImageSize = req.file.size;

}else{

    //if there was no image uploaded!!
    //noimage.png should be placed in public/images/uploads
    mainImageName = 'noimage.png';
}
```